# Multiple linear regression with GEKKO

Tags: python, linear-regression, gekko

Okay, so I need to complete a linear regression in which I fit predicted histograms to an experimental set. The relationship must be linear, and I know for a fact that there are possible solutions. Honestly, I'm pretty sure the issue is with what data types I chose with GEKKO. This is my first time using it. I either get that there are negative degrees of freedom or that there is no solution :/. If it helps, each of the 8 predictions is an array of length 72, which is also the same length as y. If anyone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it

I think GEKKO is the best tool to use. I've tried statsmodels.api and scipy but neither give me enough control over the variables.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()

simulations = {'simulation1': {'x': bins, 'y': df['x1'].values},
               'simulation2': {'x': bins, 'y': df['x2'].values},
               'simulation3': {'x': bins, 'y': df['x3'].values},
               'simulation4': {'x': bins, 'y': df['x4'].values},
               'simulation5': {'x': bins, 'y': df['x5'].values},
               'simulation6': {'x': bins, 'y': df['x6'].values},
               'simulation7': {'x': bins, 'y': df['x7'].values},
               'simulation8': {'x': bins, 'y': df['x8'].values}}

n_simulations = len(simulations)

coefficients = [m.Var(value=1, lb=0, ub=1e100) for _ in range(n_simulations)]

#for i in range(n_simulations):
#    coefficients[i].FSTATUS = 1
#    coefficients[i].STATUS = 1

experimental_data = {'x': bins, 'y': df['y'].values}

x = m.Param(value=experimental_data['x'])
y_exp = m.Param(value=experimental_data['y'])

y_pred = m.CV(value=experimental_data['y'], lb=0, ub=1e100)
y_pred.FSTATUS = 1
y_pred.STATUS = 1

for i in range(len(bins)):
    m.Equation(y_pred[i] == sum([np.multiply(coefficients[j], 
                                 simulations[f'simulation{j+1}']['y'][i]) \
                                   for j in range(n_simulations)]))

m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 0  # Model Parameter Update: use this to obtain
                      #   the best fit of a data set
m.solve(disp=True)
```

Comment: What specific variable control are you looking for (that scipy doesn't have)? Can you show your data? Otherwise we won't be able to reproduce this.

Comment: @Reinderien Can't show the data as it's confidential but it's NMR data so 1 column of chem. shift and one of intensity.

Comment: Can you at least provide ranges and distributions?

Comment: @Reinderien Basically, the experimental set is a histogram (it's like a wonky gaussian curve) that spans 55-71 ppm (x-axis). Each simulation looks slightly different but are all histograms across the same range that have a different center and can be either one or two approximately gaussian peaks.

Comment: So the experimental random variable is a distorted Gaussian, and you're trying to model it with a predicted histogram (is this also a Gaussian?) Are you just looking for a Gaussian fit to get parameters of mean and stdev?

Comment: @Reinderien not exactly. The simulations are predicted subcomponents that *should* make up the experimental file. Me saying their gaussian was more to give you an example of what the distributions look like. I want to be able to fit the subcomponents and quantify each makes up

Answer (score 0):

In `IMODE=2` (parameter regression), use an `m.FV()` for the parameters and let the solver adjust them with `STATUS=1`.

```py
coefficients = [m.FV(value=1, lb=0, ub=1e10) for _ in range(n_simulations)]
coeff_status = [coefficients[i].STATUS=1 for i in range(n_simulations)]
```

Here are similar questions on Stack Overflow that may also provide ideas:

- [Constrained Multi-Linear Regression using Gekko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989874/constrained-multi-linear-regression-using-gekko)
- [How to set up GEKKO for parameter estimation from multiple independent sets of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695486/how-to-set-up-gekko-for-parameter-estimation-from-multiple-independent-sets-of-d)
- [GEKKO multivariate nonlinear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508023/gekko-multivariate-nonlinear-regression)
- [Constrained multi-variable non-linear regression using gekko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834006/constrained-multi-variable-non-linear-regression-using-gekko)
- [GEKKO Python - simple linear regression from Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473516/gekko-python-simple-linear-regression-from-documentation)

Try using `m.options.CV_TYPE=2` for a standard squared error objective. Here is [example 5 (linear and polynomial regression)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7lHkcKrn1k&list=PLLBUgWXdTBDjxcpH9hRuq-bsm_ti2UvoB&index=7) from the [documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization).

[image: Linear and Polynomial Regression]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

xm = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
ym = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.8,2.0])

#### Solution
m = GEKKO()
m.options.CV_TYPE=2
m.options.IMODE=2
# coefficients
c = [m.FV(value=0) for i in range(4)]
x = m.Param(value=xm)
y = m.CV(value=ym)
y.FSTATUS = 1
# polynomial model
m.Equation(y==c[0]+c[1]*x+c[2]*x**2+c[3]*x**3)

# linear regression
c[0].STATUS=1
c[1].STATUS=1
m.solve(disp=False)
p1 = [c[1].value[0],c[0].value[0]]

# quadratic
c[2].STATUS=1
m.solve(disp=False)
p2 = [c[2].value[0],c[1].value[0],c[0].value[0]]

# cubic
c[3].STATUS=1
m.solve(disp=False)
p3 = [c[3].value[0],c[2].value[0],c[1].value[0],c[0].value[0]]

# plot fit
plt.plot(xm,ym,'ko',markersize=10)
xp = np.linspace(0,5,100)
plt.plot(xp,np.polyval(p1,xp),'b--',linewidth=2)
plt.plot(xp,np.polyval(p2,xp),'r--',linewidth=3)
plt.plot(xp,np.polyval(p3,xp),'g:',linewidth=2)
plt.legend(['Data','Linear','Quadratic','Cubic'],loc='best')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

The polynomial regression is multiple linear regression.